# Elasticsearch DB giving Client request timeout [Status Code 504, error : Gateway Time-Out]

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to send request on Elasticsearch Db. Most of the time I get this error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 504,
  "error": "Gateway Time-out",
  "message": "Client request timeout"
}
```

Currently i have **24 GB** of data in Elasticsearch DB

System Configuration:
8 Core, 4 GB RAM, OS Ubuntu.
I have only one node in the cluster.

I am unable to find why am i getting timeout issue frequently.
Is it because the size of the data I have?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because the size of the data I have?

No, I would not say so. We have about 100 GB in our one-node-cluster and it works fine.

As for troubleshooting your problem, it is really hard to say anything as you have not given too much info.
The 24 GB is on one indice or more?
What kind of queries are you using? 
What is your heapsize?

Comment: 24 GB on multiple indices and heapsize is 1GB.

Comment: What king of queries are you using? Aggregations? Do you use Kibana to perform queries? Try to query `GET _yourIndice/_search` . If it works then it is highly improbable that it is the size of the data. You may want to increase the heapsize as well just to see what will happen, but the heapsize should not give you 504.

Comment: I am tiring to insert a single record in an index and the record has less than 10 properties, I mean JSON object with less than 10 fields

Comment: So. your indice has 10 fields and you get 504 while truing to insert a single record into that indice?
How do you communicate with ES? Are you using some king of proxy server? Did you get a proper result when you're querying that indice with a GET query?

Comment: Their is no proxy server. Even the simple GET call is not working.

Comment: @DeepeshSaheb I am just wondering. Could it be a issue with ports and firewall? Do you have your ports open?

Comment: No, because if i clean up some data from elastic, i start getting back normal responses